# Actively migrating to Super User

Tags: discussion

I've just asked [this question](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/11490/thoughts-on-network-engineering-migrating-qs-to-this-stack) over on the Super User stack.

If they're ok with the idea, this stack might be perceived as more friendly if we start migrating empty Qs.

(SE guidelines are to NOT migrate Qs that have no comments nor answers that need to be preserved.)

Comment: Based on what I have seen the other SE sites do, this would seem to be a normal practice. I have no problem migrating unanswered questions to [su] or [sf]. In fact, the [sf] guys seemed to be shocked about the SE guidelines for this, and they don't adhere to them. They told me this leads to cross-posting, and they want to just migrate rather than have an OP post it twice.

Comment: just because everyone else does it wrong (to wit, the Security stack sends this our way often) doesn't mean NE should also. Proper practice -- i've talked to staff -- is to go tochat, summon a mod, ask, then migrate, and only migrate if the Q has comments/answers.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I understand your position as a moderator; you want to follow the guidelines, and it would make sense that you follow them, absent an agreement with the moderators of the other site. I also see the [sf] moderators' point that it can lead to cross-posting.

Comment: What guideline about not migrating unanswered questions? Nobody has ever heard of this?

Comment: There's a giant "welcome to be a moderator" thing somewhere. Also, click over and read the Q on SU...

Answer (score 3):

The key differentiation is whether there is something of quality to maintain.

I have never put it into words, but this is about the process I use when determining when to migrate:

1. Is the question off topic here? If so, continue.
2. Is the question a "good question" worth saving? If so, goto #4, else continue.
3. Is there "good content" added by other users (i.e. comments/answers)? If so, consider editing the question to improve and then continue, else close.
4. Is the question on topic on another SE site? If so, migrate to that site.

If I am not sure about #2-4, I ask in the mod chat channel. While clearly home networking questions are off topic here, that doesn't make them always worth migrating to SuperUser.

Just the same as I don't want other sites to migrate any network question here, just because they are "on topic." If they are on topic and good question (or could be made good questions), then sure, send them our way.